# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when showing Toast on android lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, toast

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=7; index=7
at android.content.res.Resources.toPreloadCookie(Resources.java:2447)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2475)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3806)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:492)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:200)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:196)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:192)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:254)
at com.A.B.C.onPostExecute(SourceFile:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5321)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
```

I'm receiving some bug reports like this and only from Sony Lollipop(5.0.2, API21) users. No reports from any other Lollipop users. I'm wondering what could be the problem, Sony had buggy implementation or something new required on Lollipop ?

Edit: Added code

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"toast text",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Could you post some codes about this error?

Comment: How are you building your toast?

Comment: This is not because of Toast, check where you access Array elements

Comment: Try using `this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: Not the problem with the Toast. You're accessing ArrayIndex that's none. Post the code that is so people can figure the problem out.

Comment: please post the complete class code where the toast is.

Comment: Dear @JemshitIskenderov, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException doesn't mean its happening because of my code. Please read the stacktrace carefully. Strange how people upvoted the comment without even reading the actual question. @ Others, Writing entire code is irrelevant, for showing toast only one line is used on button click, which I have posted. As has been said, its all working good in 99% devices, only few had this problem. Please see my answer for more info.

Comment: problem is not in the toast post the more code block to understand the problem.

Comment: @xmen: You should have kept the question just as it is. No issue is unresolved. If it came once, it will come again in production. Choice is yours.

Comment: @VinodJaiswal : whats the point ? I posted a question, I posted my own answer explaining how I solved it. But what did I got ? down voted. So I deleted my answer, I could remove the question if it was allowed. This site give morons a right to down vote, who cant even read the question or understand simple English or even a stacktrace. Actually I don't care anymore. I'm done with humans.

Comment: @xmen most people don't really read or if they read and dont understand at once then downvote immediately, you need to write so even 10 year old could understand otherwise you get downvotes. How you solved it?

Comment: @xmen: Chill. Take it easy my friend. I understand your concern, but most of the people, dont even read the questions, they just down vote it or some of them even abuse.
But some people do help others and we are here to help each other, share our knowledge.
Cutting to point, post your answer and just go with the flow.

Comment: @xmen how did you fix this? I'm having the exact same issue

Comment: @xmen I have up voted you!  I presume Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"toast text",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); was your fix?? I am having a similar issue with AlertDialog and Sony devices, so any clue as to how you solved it would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use Application context to create Toast, the same with Service/ContentProvider/BroadcastReceiver context. You can read section **Context Capabilities** in this article: [Context, What Context?](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/)

Hope it helpful.